# Interactive nodes in javascript?

Tags: html, graph, d3.js

I'd like to create a force based graph layout of nodes. I'd like the nodes to be squares with a title, a link and an image. Is this possible using D3? Any direction for how to handle this? (obviously I'm a bit new to this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, very possible.  You can see http://bl.ocks.org/950642 for an example that is pretty close to what you are looking for.  You just need to append a `rect` similar to how the text and image are appended in the example.

Comment: Sure, you'll want to store the `href` of the desired image for each node and then when inserting the image `.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.href; })`.